# The use of Artificial Intelligence in physics resarch

Tags: experimental-physics, computational-physics

I have been reading about a [machine that observed a double pendulum](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/natural_laws) and created equations that both described its motion and associated conservation laws. The authors claims:

> We have developed a technique for extracting the laws of nature from
>   experimental data by identifying invariant and conservation equations.
>   We demonstrated this approach by automatically searching
>   motion-tracking data captured from various physical systems, ranging
>   from simple harmonic oscillators to chaotic double-pendula. Without
>   any prior knowledge about physics, kinematics or geometry, the
>   algorithm discovered Hamiltonians, Lagrangians, and other laws of
>   geometric and momentum conservation.

This appears remarkable, not least because it took Humans thousands of years to discover these same facts. Are such machines being used in more difficult areas such as quantum gravity or string theory?

Comment: It is a specific request for information on the use of AI and genetic algorithms as tools in modern theoretical physics. If you can come up with a list of such projects I will be happy.

Comment: I feel like there are some really nasty snakes under the grass with this. Surely, they must have told the machine to search for certain types of equations...

Comment: @Danu it could have just tracked the data and done mathematical fits. Then used that to make laws

Comment: Laws are statements of observations, after all. If it observes in the data that certain values are conserved, stating that those values are conserved is "discovering" a law

Comment: But this seems mostly observation based. Quantum gravity, string theory, etc. These are all less observation based. You can make observations after a while, but thought experiments, imagination, and trial and error are kind of needed to get to some of those areas. I doubt this thing could do that

Comment: @Jim Fits, based on what? Surely, one must tell it what kind of variables to look for. This is a *major* issue for any more complicated theories

Comment: "Without any knowledge about physics or geometry, the system identified the exact energy conservation and momentum relations that govern its dynamcis " how is it possible to do that . This is in the faq of that link.

Comment: When it says without knowledge of geometry, does it mean geometry of the system? Or does that mean it can't perform mathematics? Because If it can do math, you can tell it to track objects and apply a whole range of trial fits to the data. I'm sure they've developed some ingenious new algorithm that determines the best function to try to fit the data to

Comment: Which, if that's the case, would be immensely helpful and I'd love them for it

Comment: When I read stuff like that I wonder whether it is the future of theoretical physics. The downside might be that a machine creates successful "theories" ie systems of equations, whose background and derivation we just cannot understand

Comment: http://news.vanderbilt.edu/2011/10/robot-biologist/

Answer (score 2):

One example I can give of using Algorithmic (Statistical) Inference in contemporary Physics research is solving the inverse problem in material science. That is, what should be the chemical composition and structure of a material if it is to have given macroscopic properties (within some tolerance range). These properties could be spectral, band-gap, etc. and the output could be chemical formula and unit cell configuration.

To learn more, please see the DOE Office of Science project http://www.centerforinversedesign.org/